# How to get a domain name from url string?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have several urls like,

[https://example.com/](http://#)
[http://example.com/](http://#)

I only want "example.com" as string

And I want to remove the

> https:// and http://

So I have taken array like this,

```
$removeChar = ["https://", "http://", "/"];
```

What is the proper way to remove these?

Comment: parse_url() http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Thanks @splash58. It was a great help.

Comment: @splash58 @Keyur for this specific example I am not sure `parse_url()` is the best option, because it returns an associative array with a non predictable amount of keys (i.e you would have to test if "query" exists, etc), considering you only want to get rid of the scheme part, in this case you would have to either remove the scheme part and then join all other parts together in a string. I would personally go with a simple `str_replace`.

Comment: @zoubida13 then don't forget to remove `port'

Comment: @splash58 well that's my point

Comment: @zoubida13 you are very true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
$http_referer = str_replace($removeChar, "", "https://example.com/");
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this php function.

> Link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php (parse_url php function)

```
$url = "http://example.com/";
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

get a result `example.com`

Comment: I believe parse_url return nothing if not http. For example: $url = "example.com";

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$string = url ... ( your url);    
$removeChar= array("http://","https://","/");    
foreach($char in $removeChar)
{    
    $string= str_replace($char,"",$string);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is builtin function :

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: But if the url is in the form `http://example.com/login?test=1` then you will only get `example.com`. See my comment on OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://www.example.com";

// Remove http:// or https:// from beginning of string
$url = preg_replace('/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/', '', $url);

echo $url; // Output: www.example.com
```